# Using bluetoothctl to reset time on smartwatch (linux)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am new to using bluetoothctl and am looking for some advice.

So, I try the following:

```
$ bluetoothctl power on
Changing power on succeeded

$ bluetoothctl devices
Device B3:50:46:84:F1:CF M6
```

The M6 is the smartwatch.

```
$ bluetoothctl connect  B3:50:46:84:F1:CF
Attempting to connect to B3:50:46:84:F1:CF
Connection successful
```

Great!

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[M6   ]# info
Device B3:50:46:84:F1:CF (public)
    Name: M6   
    Alias: M6   
    Appearance: 0x00c8
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    WakeAllowed: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Unknown                   (0000fffa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Unknown                   (0000ffff-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9d)
    Modalias: usb:v1915pEEEEd0001
    Battery Percentage: 0x36 (54)


[M6   ]# menu gatt
Menu gatt:
Available commands:
-------------------
list-attributes [dev/local]                       List attributes
select-attribute <attribute/UUID>                 Select attribute
attribute-info [attribute/UUID]                   Select attribute
read [offset]                                     Read attribute value
write <data=xx xx ...> [offset] [type]            Write attribute value
acquire-write                                     Acquire Write file descriptor
release-write                                     Release Write file descriptor
acquire-notify                                    Acquire Notify file descriptor
release-notify                                    Release Notify file descriptor
notify <on/off>                                   Notify attribute value
clone [dev/attribute/UUID]                        Clone a device or attribute
register-application [UUID ...]                   Register profile to connect
unregister-application                            Unregister profile
register-service <UUID> [handle]                  Register application service.
unregister-service <UUID/object>                  Unregister application service
register-includes <UUID> [handle]                 Register as Included service in.
unregister-includes <Service-UUID><Inc-UUID>      Unregister Included service.
register-characteristic <UUID> <Flags=read,write,notify...> [handle] Register application characteristic
unregister-characteristic <UUID/object>           Unregister application characteristic
register-descriptor <UUID> <Flags=read,write...> [handle] Register application descriptor
unregister-descriptor <UUID/object>               Unregister application descriptor
back                                              Return to main menu
version                                           Display version
quit                                              Quit program
exit                                              Quit program
help                                              Display help about this program
export                                            Print environment variables
```

Now, what i want to do is to set the date and time on this smartwatch. I am also interested in reading other information such as heart rate, temperature, etc. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You listed all the BLE services the m6 offers. The functionality you are looking for is most likely hidden behind the two unknown or the one vendor specific services. I imagine you would normaly use an app to do what you are trying to replicate? Without a documentation for the custom services your only chance is to try to figure it out yourself. Take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@sayliambure/hacking-a-5-smartband-824763ab6e8f) to find a description on how someone did this with the m4 smartband

Comment: Use `gatttool` for BLE, not `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan, thanks for the link. Separately, to Mr. Panda, isn't gatttool deprecated?